# When does ‘bekommen’ take ‘haben’ or ‘sein’ in the perfect?

Tags: past-participle, perfect-tense

In which cases would we use *sein* or *haben* as the auxiliary for *bekommen* in the perfect?

Which is more commonly used?

I saw that the second answer to [a question on Yahoo! Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090507053640AAGU8Zz) may be correct, but I certainly cannot trust Yahoo! Answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bekommen* as a transitive verb (meaning *to get*) forms the perfect tense with *haben*, like almost all transitive verbs:

> Ich habe ganz schön Angst bekommen. Lisa hat eine Eins in Mathe bekommen.

On the other hand, *bekommen* as an intransitive verb (meaning *to agree with*, of things not people) has *sein* as the auxiliary:

> Der viele Wein ist ihm nicht bekommen. Der Urlaub ist mir gut bekommen.

See also this question: [When to use "sein" and "haben" for verbs that allow both auxiliary verbs?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/when-to-use-sein-and-haben-for-verbs-that-allow-both-auxiliary-verbs)

Comment: Great and detailed answer, like the link. Just one question: Why would 'sein' be the auxiliary if it is not movement from A to B nor a change of state? And also, which form of bekommen is more commonly used?

Comment: It could be argued that the intransitive _bekommen_ indeed expresses a change of state. Think of the drinker who is well in the beginning, then gradually becomes dizzy and sick; or the overworked person who goes on holiday and recovers. It is admittedly not the typical case, though, because it is not the grammatical subject that changes. Perhaps it is one of the few exceptions. – I believe that the transitive _bekommen_ is more common, but I have no numbers to back this up.