# When to use "sein" or "haben" as an auxilliary verb?

Tags: perfect-tense, auxiliary-verb

In German, we are learning present perfect tense. According to the book, typically a past tense is used with the auxiliary verb haben, as so:

> Du **hast** das gut gelernt. (You have learned that well.)

However, some verbs use sein instead; to be so the book states it must be intransitive and express a change of place or condition, like so:

> Wir **sind** nach Hause gegangen. (We went home.)
>
> Er **ist** müde geworden. (He got tired.)

However, something that always confused my teacher is the past tense of bleiben (to remain/stay). This seems to be expressing the opposite of the rules because it is *not* changing.

My theory on this is that it's similar to how sein is in the way that it's talking about state. Also, because it's past tense, it displays change in condition in the sense that though the subject was staying in the past, they are no longer now. However, I'm not sure if this is the true reason for it since I'm not a native speaker. Could someone more acquainted with the language explain why this is so?

(Excerpts are taken from the textbook "Wie geht's?", ninth edition.)

Comment: For questions on verbs that allow both, *sein*, or *haben* [see this Q & A](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/when-to-use-sein-and-haben-for-verbs-that-allow-both-auxiliary-verbs)

Answer (score 7):

I think you’ve hit the nail on the head with the “state” change/lack of change. It’s a state of being, similar to *sein* itself.

According to Martin Durrell in *Using German: A guide to contemporary usage*, the rules are “simple” but a little more than what your textbook lists.

Sein verbs:

- intransitive verbs which express a change of place
- intransitive verbs which express a change of state
- verbs meaning *to happen, to fail, to succeed*
- the verbs *sein* and *bleiben* (It gets its own bullet point … nearly!)
- regionally, some other words get *sein* that would normally get *haben* (North: anfangen/beginnen, South: liegen/sitzen/stehen)

Haben verbs:

- transitive verbs
- reflexive verbs
- intransitive verbs expressing continuous action
- impersonal verbs (He gives the example, *Es hat geregnet.*)

So for the intransitives, you could perhaps really simplify it by saying “intransitive verbs that don’t express continuous action” get *sein*, which covers discrete movement, state change and “state of being” verbs.

Comment: An important note: many, many verbs express changes of state and take *haben*, e.g. *zerstören*. What seems important is: is it a change of state *of the subject*?

Comment: Zerstören is transitive, that is, it takes a direct object. It seems that all transitive verbs use *haben*.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to learn together with the verb if it needs *haben* or *sein*, like you have to learn the gender of every noun separately (i.e. which article to use with it).

To learn the auxiliar verbs for full verbs it is a little bit easier than learning the articles of nouns, because they are a little more systematic, but if you ask a typical German native speaker about those systematics, most of them will answer that they don't know any of them. This is because a native speaker knows for every individual verb which auxiliary it needs.

One rule of thumb is:

**Verbs of movement (gehen, laufen, fliegen, ...) need *»sein«:***

> Ich **bin** nach Hause gefahren. (*I drove home.*)
>   Wir **sind** im Meer geschwommen. (*We swam in the sea.*)

But watch this:

> Andrea **hat** das Auto gefahren.

Here *fahren* is not used in the sense of changing position (= movement), but in the sense of operating a machine (i.e. a car). So it can't be treated as a verb of movement here.

It also makes a difference, if you use a verb transitive or intransitive:

- intransitive:

  > Der Henkel **ist** abgebrochen. (*The handle has broken.*)
- transitive:

  > Der Benutzer **hat** *den Vorgang* **abgebrochen.** (*The user has canceled the operation.*)

Some verbs also have two or more different meanings, which sometimes also go with different auxiliary verbs:

> Dieser Stab ist unbrauchbar. Er **ist** gebrochen. (*This rod is unusable. It is broken.*)
>   Hans hat zu viel Bier getrunken. Er **hat** gebrochen. (*Hans drank too much beer. He vomited.*)

Also know, that for some words there are regional differences. Prominent examples are the verbs *»stehen«, »liegen«* and *»sitzen«* (*to stand, to lie* and *to sit*):

- In the middle and north of German speaking area

  > Ich **habe** an der Haltestelle gestanden.
  >   Ich **habe** im Bett gelegen.
  >   Ich **habe** auf dem Stuhl gesessen.
- In the south (specially in Austria)

  > Ich **bin** an der Haltestelle gestanden.
  >   Ich **bin** im Bett gelegen.
  >   Ich **bin** auf dem Sessel<sup>*</sup> gesessen.

The geographic border between those two versions is not exactly the border between Germany and Austria. Very often you find variations that are typical for Austria also in Bavaria.

*<sup>* Stuhl and Sessel also have different meanings in Germany and Austria.</sup>*

Comment: There are only very few verbs where you need to know they take *sein*. For the rest there are fairly simple rules. Native speakers 'know' when to use *sein* or *haben*, but for German-learners it makes sense to learn those rules

Answer (score 1):

"Sein" is used as an auxiliary verb:

- for the verbs "sein", "passieren", "bleiben", "werden".
- for intransitive verbs and non-reflexive verbs that indicate movement or a change in state e.g.: rennen, springen, laufen, fallen, gehen, sterben, schmelzen

"Haben" is used in all other cases.

Some verbs can be either transitive or intransitive depending on context, so they can have sein or haben as an auxiliary verb e.g.: 
fahren, biegen, verderben, brechen, fliegen, treten, schneiden, reiten

Answer (score 0):

If you move somehow you have to use sein, else you have to use haben.

So the answer is no, Wir sind im Meer geschwommen und wir haben Musik gehört, because to swim is a movement.

Other examples:

> Ich bin gerannt - I was running
>
> Ich habe gelesen - I was reading
>
> Ich bin gefahren - I was driving
>
> Ich habe gespielt - I was playing

But there are a lot of tricky ones, some examples:

> Ich habe getanzt - I was dancing
>
> Ich bin gestorben - I was dying

Comment: *Ich **habe** mich bewegt.* – Most verbs of movement use *sein* but it's still only a rule of thumb. There's often a difference in transitive vs. intransitive: *Ich bin gefahren.* vs. *Ich habe ihn gefahren.*