# Das Verb vorbereiten im Perfekt mit sein und haben

Tags: perfect-tense

Könnte jemand mir erklären, was der Unterschied zwischen *vorbereitet* mit *haben* und *vorbereitet* mit *sein* ist?
Es wäre noch besser, wenn es noch einen Beispielsatz gäbe.

Comment: Ähnliche aber allgemeiner gehaltene Frage (auf Englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/when-to-use-sein-and-haben-for-verbs-that-allow-both-auxiliary-verbs

Answer (score 5):

"Vorbereitet haben" bedeutet, dass man *etwas* vorbereitet hat, zum Beispiel eine Mahlzeit oder etwas zum Vorführen. Die Vorbereitung des Objektes ist bereits geschehen.

> Ich habe den Versuch vorbereitet. Wenn die Zuschauer da sind, muss ich nur noch auf den Startknopf drücken, um die Vorführung zu beginnen.

"Vorbereitet sein" bezeichnet einen Zustand, in dem man sich befindet. Man ist auf etwas (ein Ereignis) vorbereitet.

> Ich habe für die mündliche Prüfung gelernt. Ich bin auf jede Frage, die der Prüfer stellen könnte, vorbereitet.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Jetzt ist mir alles klar :)

Answer (score 3):

Sehr einfach:

> vorbereitet sein

ist ein [Zustandspassiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zustandspassiv), das Subjekt *hat sich vorbereitet* oder *wurde von jemand anderem vorbereitet*, und das Ergebnis davon ist eben der Zustand. Im Englischen würde man sagen *he is prepared*.

> vorbereitet haben

ist dagegen Aktiv, und bedeutet, dass das Subjekt aktiv eine Tätigkeit (die des Vorbereitens) ausübt oder ausgeübt hat. Im Englischen würde man sagen *he has prepared sth/so*

Ein Beispielsatz, in dem beide Formen vorkommen, könnte z.B.

> Er hat sich gut auf seine Prüfung vorbereitet und ist jetzt vorbereitet für den großen Tag

(Was natürlich, wegen des doppelten Vorkommens von "vorbereitet" nicht besonders stilsicher klingt)

Comment: Vielen Dank!. Ich habe gerade gestern das Zustandspassiv gelernt, aber es halt noch nicht im Kopf ganz fest. Jetzt ist mir alles klar.

Comment: @ tofro: "Er ... ist SICH jetzt bereit ... für den großen Tag." - Ich glaube, ich bin MIR jetzt versucht, MIR über dich zu :-)) :-))

Comment: @multiplexetliber Schlecht vorbereitet, eben ;) Danke!

Comment: @tofro  Keine Ursache! Dass das nur 'n Flüchtigkeitsfehler war, war klar. Aber ob moluzka das auch gewusst hat? Da hab' ich halt gelacht, weil der Hinweis dann nich' als 'Ermahnung' rüberkommt. Freut mich, dass du's nich' in den falschen Hals gekriegt hast.

Answer (score 2):

Man sollte sich der Tatsache bewußt sein, daß ein Partizip II auch ein Adjektiv sein kann. *Der Schüler ist gut vorbereitet* kann parallel zu *er ist hungrig* gesehen werden. Als Adjektiv kann *vorbereitet* auch ohne *sein*, nämlich attributiv und als sekundäres Prädikat auftreten. Es kann mit dem Präfix *un-* negiert werden.

> ein gut vorbereiteter Schüler
>   Der Schüler kam völlig unvorbereitet in die Prüfung.

Als Adjektiv kann ein Partizip II eine Bedeutung entwickeln, die vom zugrundeliegenden Verb abweicht.

> Der Wein schmeckt ausgezeichnet.
>   Was für ein ausgezeichneter Wein!

Das Adjektiv *ausgezeichnet* bedeutet hier einfach nur *sehr gut* und nicht *prämiert*. Weitere Beispiele für die Selbständigkeit des Adjektivs:

> ein ausgefallener Vorschlag, ein aufgeweckter Bursche, eine gut aufgelegte Runde, ...