# What to use "sein" or "haben" for heilen in Perfekt?

Tags: verb, perfect-tense

Guten Tag.

I faced a new word - "heilen". Nice one and it looks really familiar (to heal). Usually I look for simple sentences with the word to add them into my memory-program. But with this word I have a little issue.

I found out that it may be used in Perfekt with both "haben" and "sein":

- Er hat ihn geheilt
- Sie ist geheilt
- Sie hat sie geheilt
- Er hat dein Herz geheilt
- Sie ist fast geheilt

I didn't find any rules about it yet. Also I see that different dictionaries provides different auxiliary word (haben or sein).

But it seems that I see the pattern. For me it looks like:

- If somebody heals somebody - use "haben akk. ... geheilt"
- If somebody heals himself - use "sein ... geheilt"

So I have some questions:

- Do I understand it correctly?
- Is there any general logic behind it, or is it something specifically related only to "heilen"?
- Is there any simple way to find out when to use sein/haben with words like this, that supports both (like umziehen)?

Comment: In the case of "heilen", it's actually simple: when used intransitively, *sein* is used, when used transitively, *haben* is used.

Comment: Thank you. So when I have some object to what the verb acts I use haben, and when there's no such an object - sein. Hm. It's simple.

Comment: I have added your link below as an answer

Comment: It's not the same with all verbs. There are several categories of verbs with respect to *haben* and *sein*. See e.g. the first answer to the question I posted. "Heilen" belongs to the category "verbs which express change of state".

Comment: Actually, "sie ist geheilt" is not perfect but *Zustandspassiv*.

Comment: Danke! I guess that, cause it looks like English passive voice. I'll take a look at this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [there](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/when-to-use-sein-and-haben-for-verbs-that-allow-both-auxiliary-verbs) (thx @rha and @david-vogt)

The general rule for many of German verbs that can be used with both "sein" and "haben":

- Transitive case: there's some object, to which this verb acts - HABEN
- Intransitive case: If there's no such an object - SEIN